# How does a parent thread in a thread pool obtain data stored in thread local by a child thread

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, threadpool, java-11, thread-local

I have a threadlocal that records logs, and I want to add all logs of this request to the return result when returning the result. Normal use is no problem, but when using thread pool, due to the characteristics of threadlocal, the logs printed in the child thread are stored in the threadlocal of the child thread. How can I get the log data saved by the child threads to thread local in the main thread

Comment: If you have something that is not supposed to be local to a single thread, don’t use a thread local.

Comment: I needed a common variable to store the logs of each request, but the logs of each request could not be mixed together and needed to be distinguished so I used thread local, Now the problem is that when I request that I add my main thread to the thread local from the thread pool I can't get the thread local log from the thread pool

Comment: A “log” is an object isn’t it? So if you include the information about the associated request in each log object, you can put them into a common queue and still tell apart. Or what if you “add all logs of this request to the return result” in the child thread instead of the main thread? Or let the main thread provide the request specific log storage to the child job in the first place?

Comment: public static ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

The above variable is a class variable, I need to distinguish the logs of each request, so I use thread local. If it is a public queue, two requests operate this variable at the same time, won't the logs of the two requests get mixed up? This is not the result I want. Any good advice? I need help

Comment: Don’t use a `String`. Use an object encapsulating the `String` and a job identifier. Alternatively, pass the right `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instance to the job when creating the job. But note that [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) is the wrong tool for the job. It’s efficient when “*when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations*” but your scenario is the absolute opposite of it, potentially lots of modifications, followed by a single traversal at the end.

Comment: So what should I use instead of CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> in this scenario, because I need to use a concurrent safe collection type for thread pools, and what should I use instead of String

Comment: As long as each thread has its own instance, as the use of `ThreadLocal` implies, there is no need for thread safety and even `ArrayList` would do. But if you follow one of the suggestions to eliminate the thread local variable, you can use a `ArrayBlockingQueue`, for example. For your log items, just create your own class holding the string and a job identifier.

Comment: Well, thank you for your help and advice